# Inno Setup how to merge 2 different "send to" filenames?

Tags: send-to

In the [Icons] section I created 2 entries the first wil move any image to the "DropWall" folder, the second will launch my "InsideWallpaper.exe" using the same image:

```
Name: "{sendto}\FFStyled (I) set InsideWallpaper image";
Filename: "{app}\DropWall";
IconFilename: "{app}\FFDropWall.ico";
Tasks: sendtoicon

Name: "{sendto}\FFStyled (II) launch InsideWallpaper.exe";
Filename: "{app}\InsideWallpaper.exe";
IconFilename: "{app}\FFDropWall.ico";
Tasks: sendtoicon
```

all is working fine but I would prefer to create a single "send to" entry
any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of scripting to sort out the action, eg in `cmd` create the short-cut:-

```
Name: "{sendto}\FFStyled handle InsideWallpaper image";
Filename: "{app}\Wallpaper.cmd";
IconFilename: "{app}\FFDropWall.ico";
Tasks: sendtoicon
```

In `{app}\Wallpaper.cmd` put code such as:-

```
echo off
set app="{app}\DropWall"
if "%~dp1"=="{wallpaper}\" set app="{app}\InsideWallpaper.exe"
"%app%" "%1"
```

Here `{sendto}`, `{app}` and `{wallpaper}` represent the corresponding directories. Note that, even when there are surrounding quotes in the passed parameter `%1`, there aren't in the parsed drive / directory `%~dp1`, though there is a trailing back-slash.

For more information, type `if /?` and `call /?`, or see [this link](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) and [this](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

Comment: first of all thanks for the nice editing any way I really prefer to find the solution using Inno Setup as I said the script is perfectly working but it will populate the user "send to" with 2 entries

Comment: I doubt you will be able to achieve that without getting the manufacturer to do it, unless there is an installation script you can modify, in which case you'll need the information above to know what modifications to make.